# ROS - Turtlebot simulator problem: the turtlebot model does not appear on Gazebo

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i'm a beginner with ROS world.

I use Ubuntu 16.04 (on virtual machine), Kinetic, gazebo 7.

When i execute `roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch`, Gazebo starts and models of the 3D world appear, but there is no turtlebot model!

The terminal give me this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache/index'
[spawn_turtlebot_model-3] process has died [pid 4179, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_model -unpause -urdf -param robot_description -model mobile_base __name:=spawn_turtlebot_model __log:=/home/user/.ros/log/62c9e862-31d6-11e8-b9a2-080027f2d824/spawn_turtlebot_model-3.log].
log file: /home/user/.ros/log/62c9e862-31d6-11e8-b9a2-080027f2d824/spawn_turtlebot_model-3*.log
```

I do not understand anything. How to solve?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286756/ros---turtlebot-simulator-problem:-the-turtlebot-model-does-not-appear-on-gazebo./) by [Cholopineco](https://answers.ros.org/users/34338/cholopineco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-03-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache/index'
> ```

you've ran `sudo rosdep update` at some point in the past.

You shouldn't do that (and you should also have been given a warning about that by `rosdep`).

Try the following and see whether things improve:

```
sudo rosdep fix-permissions
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cholopineco](https://answers.ros.org/users/34338/cholopineco/) on 2018-03-28**:
it works! Thanks so much for helping!